# What does this Emacs error mean?

Tags: emacs

What does the following error message mean, and how can I resolve it?

> An error has occurred while loading `/Users/JaydenXu/.emacs':
>
> Symbol's value as variable is void: ...
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with
>   the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: Try to find literal `...` in your `.emacs` file and either delete or comment out. See post below for in depth explanation.

Comment: An error has occurred while loading `/Users/JaydenXu/.emacs':

End of file during parsing: /Users/JaydenXu/.emacs

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

Comment: something has changed......

Answer (score 1):

The `.emacs` configuration file in your home directory contains an error.

The contents of this file should be valid code in the LISP dialect that emacs speaks. On startup emacs parses this file and executes the code contained in it.

It is difficult to tell exactly where to repair without seeing the contents of your `.emacs` file.

Nevertheless the error message gives a hint. As it reported the parser found a sequence of three periods `...` that it could not expand.

Open your `.emacs` file and locate `...` in it. You may either remove them or comment out the line putting at least one `;` as first character on the line.

Before messing around be sure to make a named backup of your `.emacs` file.

If you are lucky enough there may still be a working backup (`.emacs~`) of an older and hopefully working version of your `.emacs` file around.

In this case you could either revert to to the old version or `diff` both versions to spot the error.